# Shiny App to Run Simple Regression-Error: Reading objects from shinyoutput object not allowed

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to write a shinyapp that allows users to choose a dependent variable and select a number of independent variables and the app outputs the regression table.

Currently the code I have looks like the following.

ui.R

```
# Define UI for application 

shinyUI(fluidPage( 

#application title 

titlePanel("Data Analysis Write-Up"), 

#sidebar 

sidebarLayout( 
    sidebarPanel( 

        textInput("name", label=h5("Name"), value="Name"), 
        HTML('</br>'), 
        selectInput("dv", h5("Choose a dependent variable:"), 
                choices = c("Female Legislators", "Literacy Rate", "Renewable Resources")),
        HTML('</br>'), 
        checkboxGroupInput("iv", label= h5("Independent Variables"), 
                choices = list("GDP per capita"= 1, "Population"=2, "Poverty"=3),
                selected= c(1,2,3)), 
        HTML('</br>'), 
        radioButtons('format', h5("Document Format"), c('PDF', "Word"), inline=T), 
        downloadButton('downloadReport')),

#main panel 

mainPanel(

        tabPanel("Model",                   
                       verbatimTextOutput("model"),
                       textInput("text_model", label = "Interpretation", value = "Enter text..."))
                )
 ))))
```

server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    
      
load("/Users/KimFruge/Desktop/CPO2002Sum2016/Lectures/Writing Assignment/dat.RData")
      
#Dependent Variables 
      
output$dv <- reactive({ switch(input$dv, 
    "Female Legislator"= SG.GEN.LSOM.ZS, 
    "Literacy Rate" =  SE.ADT.LITR.ZS,
          "Renewable Resources" = EG.ELC.RNWX.ZS) 
})


#Independent Variables


x<-c("NY.GDP.PCAP.CD", "SP.POP.TOTL", "SI.POV.2DAY") 

output$iv<- reactive({ x[input$iv] }) 

#data 

temp<- reactive({ 
      
      dat[, c("country", "year", output$dv, output$iv)]
      
      })


#regression formula 

          regFormula<- reactive({ 
                
                    as.formula(paste(output$dv, '~', output$iv))
                
                })

#Regression Model 

    model<- reactive ({ 

         lm(regFormula(), data = temp())

     })

#model 


    output$model <- renderPrint({ summary(model())}) 

  })

 })
```

The app runs and the side panel shows up like I want it to but I get the error "Reading objects from shinyoutput object not allowed".

What could be producing this error? Where could I look for errors, or what are common mistakes that produce this error?

Note: The data for this project was simply downloaded from world bank indicators.

Comment: You have several `output$dv` in your server code, which probably should be `input$dv`.

Comment: @warmoverflow if I change it to `input$dv` then it says undefined columns since that corresponds to the "description" of the variable and not the name itself. Possible I can change these to match but it is not ideal. Thanks!

Comment: You can set `choices` to be a named list with names and values, then names will be displayed but values will be the returned value. see `?selectInput` for usage.

Comment: @warmoverflow I just figured that one out! Thanks for the help!